# I am not able to create temporary table in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

got below error while trying to create temporary table in Bigquery .

create  or replace temporary table mss.Business.test2 as
select * from mss.Business.registration

Query error: Temporary tables may not be qualified at [2:36]

Comment: You can't create **temp** table on the dataset, so use **create temp table test2 as select * from mss.Business.registration** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jaytiger names are not included in the `CREATE TEMP TABLE` statement.

You can create temporary table to store the results of a query as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE <table1> as (SELECT * FROM `<dataset>.<table2>`);
SELECT * from <table1>
```

You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/multi-statement-queries#create_temporary_table) for further examples on Temp tables.